# How to implement site map path with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4, try to show a site map path on the page, for example: Home > Customer > Orders > Details. Except for [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), is there any other approach to implement a "dynamic" site map path?

I want to know if it's possible that I skip the XML site map file and create a site map path dynamically (at runtime). Since I just need a "bread crumb", not a site menu. It would be great if there are example code showing how people implement it.

Comment: Yes, there are other ways. You could write code for example. But why would you want to reinvent the wheels when there's already a component for that? Besides what's your question?

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear. I want to know if it's possible that I skip the XML site map file and create a site map path dynamically (at runtime). Since I just need a "bread crumb", not a site menu. It would be great if there are example code showing how people implement it.

Comment: Altight, then go ahead and edit your question to include this information.

Comment: http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/xml-sitemap-with-aspnet-mvc